# vector subspace proof 3

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to do the following:

I need to determine if the following subset of $M_n(\Bbb R)$ is actually subspaces:

$ U = \{A \in M_n\Bbb (R) : A^t \neq A\}$.

My solution so far:

I know that I need to prove the following for a subset to be a subspace

1)U is not empty
2)u+v∈U
3)for all a∈R

Here is the logic I have came up with:

if I let the following scalers be $\alpha = \beta = 1$ and
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right]\quad B = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right] $$
Looking at both of these, I can see that they do not equal their transpose.

However from here on I am not quite sure how to proceed, looking for some help.

Comment: Is the zero vector in U?

Comment: I believed that it was, can you further explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector space must include the zero vector, in this case, say  $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

What can you say about its transpose?

Indeed, we have $A=A^T$.

The absence of the zero vector (the $n\times n$ matrix with entries all $0$ is sufficient to conclude that $U$ is not a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb R).$

Please realize that to prove additive closure of $U$ such that if $A\in U$ and $B \in U$,  then $A+B \in U$, you'd need to show it for every such matrix $A$ and $B \in U$.  You cannot prove such closure by picking just two specific matrices to test.  You would need to represent $A\in U, A = \begin{bmatrix} w&x\\ y&z\end{bmatrix}$, then find $A^T\neq A$. And also $B\in U, \;B = \begin{bmatrix} p&q \\ r&s \end{bmatrix}$, then finding $B^T \neq B$ with $p, q, r, s, w, x, y, z \in \mathbb R$. And then, you'd need establish whether $A + B \neq (A+B)^T$.

Alternatively, if you believe that closure does not hold when testing whether a subset is a subspace, then to prove closure is not satisfied, you may find two vectors (matrices) in the subset and show that their sum is not in the subset.  In your case, for example, using the specific matrices you named $A$, $B$, respectively, note that $A+B = 0_2$, the zero vector, which we've already seen does not belong to $U$. Because $A+B \notin U$, we found a "counterexample" which clearly shows $U$ is not a subspace.

Comment: Whatever the $n$ in $M_n(\mathbb R)$, the corresponding zero matrix of dimension $n\times n$ is equal to its transpose, and hence, not in U.

Comment: so that is enough to show that this subset is not a subspace?

Comment: what about the other two things we need to prove, the addition and multiplication?

Comment: oh wait, so when A is the zero vector then A^t is still equal to the 0 vector so A = A^t which contradicts the question?

Comment: @ amWhy is this correct?

Comment: awesome thanks for your time

Comment: Not there now...I did address the OP's incorrect attempt to prove additive closure.